# to find a simple pole of $\;h(t)= \frac 1{2\pi i} (\frac{1}{t-z}-\frac{1}{t-\bar z})\;$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show that

If

$h(t)= \frac1{2\pi i} (\frac{1}{t-z}-\frac{1}{t-\bar z})$

for some z and t in the upper half plane, then it has a simple pole at z  only in $H^+$.

Comment: "At $\;z\;$ only ? What did you **really** mean to write?

Comment: I suppose he meant that although the possibile poles on $\mathbb{C}$ are at $z,\bar z$, since we are only considering the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ the only pole on the set of definition is at $z$

Comment: Edit **required**. The correct phrase is "has a simple pole in the upper half plane".

Comment: Yeah thanks!..@ Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$h$ has two poles at $t=z$ and $t=\bar z$. Only one of $z,\bar z$ is in the upper half plane (obviously, $z\not\in{\Bbb R}$).